# Javascript writting the value of innerHtml using document.write

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dom, innerhtml

```
<div id="para">
    <p>Lorem</p>
</div>

    var test= document.getElementById("para").innerHtml("<p>ipsum</p>");
    var test2 =document.getElementById("para");
    document.write(test2);
```

I want to write the value of test2 variable or what is inside innerHTML.But its not working,can you give me reason why that is happening.

Comment: @VincentUgenti http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dq89t5k5/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not a method, it is a property. Also to get the inner content of an element you can use the `innerHTML` property

```js
var test = document.getElementById("para").innerHTML= "<p>ipsum</p>";
var test2 = document.getElementById("para");
var tn = document.createTextNode(test2.innerHTML)
document.body.appendChild(tn)
```

```html
<div id="para">
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dq89t5k5/5/)

Comment: we can use innerHTML as both property and as a method

Comment: @amguruprasath no you cannot.  It's a property.

Comment: var name = "myName";

    function test() {
     document.write(name);
    }

    var testcheck= test();
     
    document.write(testcheck);

This returns  " myNameundefiend  " that is the value+undefined 
why is that happening ?

Comment: it's because `test` function doesn't return value, so by default it returns `undefined`. When you print `document.write(testcheck)`, testcheck contains the returned value of `test()` which is undefined. so you're getting 'myNameundefined`